# NOTEPAD++ REGEX How do I replace and remove a whitespace from $0

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex:

```
\s[0-9]+ thd
```

It finds what I want perfectly. I want to remove the white space at the beginning. What should I put in the replace field?

Comment: Can you include a sample line? Your current regex matches something like " 12 thd" and I want to make sure it's not "     thd" instead (Um, there should be multiple spaces in there after the opening quote. They got truncated...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the search text to `\s([0-9]+ thd)` and then the replacement id `\1` or `$1` depending on the type of regex.

Answer (score 1):

Find:

```
\s([0-9]+ thd)
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

Comment: Huh, another 'Jerry'. Nice to meet'cha I guess.

Answer (score 0):

So if you using Notepad++ everything in parenthesis refers to section build from `\` and `number` in **Replace** box.
Look at example:

```
    Find: (\s)([0-9]+ thd)
    Replace: \1\2
```

This give you back first `\1` and second `\2` section - nothing unusual, but when you live only `\2` after replace you'll get only part found by `([0-9]+ thd)`

Going further if you split your expression to `(\s)([0-9]+)(\s)(thd)` then you'll get 4 parts

This parts will be represented by `\1\2\3\4` and if you need add something more to your output line:

for example `added_text_before\1added_text_after` in Replace will result merging added text and section found - practice because there is no hidden magic out there.

Remember that using regex in Notepad++ have some limitations (to long expression aren't read).

Comment: What do you mean in the last part where you say "Remember that using regex in Notepad++ have some limitations (to long expression aren't read)"?

Comment: Using more than 10 groups (just rough estimation, maybe problems lay in group content, I just build expression from same simple parts) return nothing - same expression works in RubyMine without problems.

Comment: Notepad++ 6.3.2 allows more than 9 capture expressions. Using the search text `(\w)(\w)/(\w)(\w)/(\w)(\w)(\w)(\w) (\w)(\w):(\w)(\w)` and the replace text `${12}${11}/${10}$9/$8${7}$6$5 $4$3:$2$1` then the letters and digits within `12/34/5678 ab:cd` are reversed to be `dc/ba/8765 43:21`.

Comment: I didn't know about this ${10} thing since my notepad is bit old :)- thanks for good lesson